# Install Windows 7 from Disk Partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

How can I boot the windows 7 installer from a partition on my disk? (like from an USB stick)

I'm having troubles installing Windows 7 from an USB drive (I need some legacy software) next to my Windows 10 on my PC.

The PC boots from the USB stick with no issue and the Windows 7 installer initializes successfully, however, when I try to install the Windows, I am getting this message back:
[image: load driver windows 7 error]

I tried installing the USB 3.0 drivers on the usb stick, tried different ports but no luck. As I don't have an optical unit in my PC, nor any USB 2.0, thinking that installing from the partition might be the easiest thing.

Comment: If you are using a USB 3 flash storage device then you have to add USB 3 drivers to the ISO in order to install Windows 7.  Easier solution is to add the USB 3 driver and use what you already have.

Comment: Ramhound, thank you! I’ve tried to add the usb drivers on the iso - downloaded them online and used DISM to add them, but no luck. Even tho I doubt it, maybe I had the wrong drivers... how can I get the drivers that I already use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the installation was failing and couldn’t get the usb 3.0 drivers installed was because of a faulty ISO I was trying to install after.

Going on microsoft website and downloading the ISO from there, adding the drivers to the stick as described in the other answer, solved my issue.

There was no need to install from a disk partition although it would have been interesting to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Faulty USB settings in BIOS may also cause the problem. Windows 7 install media doesn’t have native support for USB3.0. So if your BIOS has any settings for USB3.0 support during start up, turn it to AUTO or DISABLE.

Also, check following suggestions in this guide for your issue: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2755139/-a-media-driver-your-computer-needs-is-missing-or-a-required-cd-dvd-dr

Comment: I’ve got an option in bios: “legacy USB support” that is set to enabled so I don’t think that is the issue

Comment: Furthermore, I know the windows 7 installer doesn’t have support for usb 3.0, tried to patch the drivers there but it didn’t work

Comment: Trying the Windows 7 USB tool in that guide right now